Can’t boot into Windows 10 from grub boot menu
Whenever I try to boot into Windows 10 from the GRUB boot menu, I get this error screen. I can boot into Ubuntu just fine, and I can boot into Windows via UEFI just fine, but when I try it from grub it always gives me this Recovery screen.


This question is similar to: Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. I'm not sure that it's worth all the trouble it could cause just to fix something that isn't broken, but this is a way to do it anyway.
